# Cant figure out how to get center of relativelayout

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I have been struggling with this for the last 2 hours, and I just can't get the answer for this. I want the center of my relativelayout because I want to draw a circle there using a canvas. What I've tried already:

- ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener
- OnStart()

Here is my code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bg); 
    rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relPaint);
    //canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
    canvas.drawCircle(centreX, centreY, 50, paint);
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        rel.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bg));
    } else {
        rel.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bg));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    centreX = rel.getX() + rel.getWidth()  / 2;
    centreY = rel.getY() + rel.getHeight() / 2;
    super.onStart();
}
```

The variables rel, centreX and centreY are declared globally. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). `onCreate()` is called before `onStart()`. You are drawing the circle first and then calculating center of the layout. Do everything in `OnCreate()`.

And calculate `centreX` and `centreY` like this.

```
rel.post(new Runnable() { 
@Override
  public void run() {
    centreX = rel.getWidth() / 2;
    centreY = rel.getHeight() / 2;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bg); 
    rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relPaint);
    //canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
    canvas.drawCircle(centreX, centreY, 50, paint);
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
      rel.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bg));
    } else {
      rel.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bg));
    }
  }
});
```